# Convert a String to an int and store the result in a variable

Tags: c++, arrays, methods

int Units;

```
void input(int i) {
    char temp[50];
    printf("Enter class id for #%d > ", i + 1);
    readLine(ClassID);      
    printf("Enter Name for #%d > ", i + 1);
    readLine(ClassName);        
    printf("Enter Description for #%d > ", i + 1);
    readLine(Description);      
    printf("Enter pre-reqs for #%d > ", i + 1);
    readLine(PreReqs);
    printf("Enter units > ");
    readLine(temp);
    // Write a method to convert String temp into an integer and store it in the Units field
```

I think I need to do something with a nested loop but I am not exactly sure how to go about the conversion please help.

Comment: Assuming you have your string as a character array, then I believe you're looking for the `atoi()` function: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

Answer (score 0):

Use the `atoi()` function from `cstdlib` (you will need to include `cstdlib` at the top of your file):

```
units = atoi(temp);
```

It converts a char array into an integer. See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/%20*here*).

You can also use `strtol()` which allows for error checking, see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/%20*here*) for details. Credit: @NathanOliver

Comment: `atoi` doesn't even allow for error checking if 0 is a possible result.

Comment: If you are going to suggest functions from `<cstdlib>` they should [`strtol()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) since you can check for errors with that.

Comment: @NathanOliver I suggsted atoi() as I could tell that the OP may find it more complicated than atoi(), judging by the question and the code posted.

Comment: There's always `stoi`, which is just as simple as `atoi` and actually has all the error checking support. Of course one would have to assume the OP is using C++11 in 2015.

Comment: and i was told after converting to put the result into the variable units?